# How do I increment a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my JSON:

```
{"0":0,"1":1,"2":2,"3","4":4,"5":5,"7":"Ocupat","8":8,"9":9,"10":10,"11":11,"12":12,"13":13,"14":14,"15":15,"16":16,"17":17,"18":18,"19":19,"20":20,"21":21,"22":22,"23":23,"24":24,"25":25}
```

this is my js code

```
function populateLocuriLibereDus(id_cursa, data_rezervare) {
var data = id_cursa + "-" + data_rezervare;
$.get(Path + 'rezervaribilete/locuridisponibile/' + data, function(o) {
$.each(o, function(i, value) {
if(value != "Ocupat"){
$('#locuridus').append('<option value="'+ value +'">'+ value +'</option>');
}
});
}, 'json');
}
```

The option are show starting from 0 to 25, I want to show from 1 to 26

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried value++ and value = value + 1; but it concatenate the current value with 1. For example if I have 0 it displays 01

Comment: you need to convert your string to an int first. try `parseInt(i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `value` with `(value+1)` when you are outputting the options.

Comment: Great! thanks. It worked. Didn't taught about this. I will accept your answer , but must pass 12 minutes